Python Backtrader RSI ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
import backtrader as bt
import pandas as pd

# Load data
file_path = r'C:\forex\python\data\EURUSD1min-v2.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)

# Handle date and time in separate columns
data['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Datetime'], format='%Y.%m.%d. %H:%M')
data.set_index('Datetime', inplace=True)

print("Data loaded, total entries:", len(data))

# Backtrader data format
class PandasData(bt.feeds.PandasData):
    params = (
        ('datetime', None),
        ('open', '<OPEN>'),
        ('high', '<HIGH>'),
        ('low', '<LOW>'),
        ('close', '<CLOSE>'),
        ('volume', None),
        ('openinterest', None),
    )

# RSI-based strategy
class RSIStrategy(bt.Strategy):
    params = (
        ('rsi_period', 14),
        ('rsi_upper', 70),
        ('rsi_lower', 30),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.rsi = bt.indicators.RSI_SMA(self.data.close, period=self.params.rsi_period)
        print("RSI indicator initialized.")

    def next(self):
        if len(self.data.close) < self.params.rsi_period:
            print("Not enough data for RSI calculation.")
            return

        current_rsi = self.rsi[0]
        current_close = self.data.close[0]

        if pd.isna(current_rsi) or current_rsi == 0:
            print("Invalid or zero RSI:", current_rsi)
            return

        print(f"Close: {current_close}, RSI: {current_rsi}")

# Load data into Backtrader
data_feed = PandasData(dataname=data)
print("Data converted to Backtrader format.")

# Create Backtrader cerebro and add strategy
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.adddata(data_feed)
cerebro.addstrategy(RSIStrategy)
print("Strategy added to Cerebro.")

# Run the strategy
cerebro.run()
print("Execution finished.")

When the program runs, (AT RSI initialization) it encounters the error message ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
The data is correct, beginning with RSI. What can the problem be? I tried many things, debug, log. But the log inside RSI also didn't work, so the problem lies somewhere with RSI.

I encountered the same issue.
I am using several drawing indicators in my strategy, as shown below:
        bt.indicators.ExponentialMovingAverage(self.datas[0], period=25)
        bt.indicators.WeightedMovingAverage(self.datas[0], period=25,subplot=True)
        # bt.indicators.StochasticSlow(self.datas[0])
        bt.indicators.MACDHisto(self.datas[0])
        rsi = bt.indicators.RSI(self.datas[0])
        bt.indicators.SmoothedMovingAverage(rsi, period=10)
        bt.indicators.ATR(self.datas[0], plot=False)

When I comment out bt.indicators.StochasticSlow(self.datas[0]), the problem does not occur.
I don't have enough time to research it,  but I hope this information is helpful to you.
